# Usage analytics on picture library : views count always 0?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, picture, site-usage, analytics

We are running a sharepoint online solution, in which we already use the usage analytics properties on many pages, to display the count of views for some elements. These elements, for which it works fine, are pages, and documents from various libraries across the whole site collection.

For example, we have a type of page which is used to display pages and documents in a Content Search WebPart, ordered by ViewsRecent. It works perfectly fine, the Views count is displayed at the bottom of each element, and well-updated. This specific type of page is used on subsites only, but we also use ViewsRecent to order some results on the homepage of the root site, and it also works. HOWEVER!

There is one library, in the root site, where the count isn't updated at all. It appears that it's a picture library, and it is the only one of its type on the site collection which needs to use the usage analytics features. And it fails.
Buttons "Most popular items" and "Trends&Popularity" both are active, but clicking them leads to either :
[image: Most popular]

Or

[image: Trends]

Where it is the same for every element : 0 everywhere.

We tried to trigger increment on these images many times, by clicking them, visiting their pages, well, anything that is (according to the MS documentation) supposed to trigger incrementation of the views count. We don't understand why the count works on other libraries, but not this one. 
For information, the pictures in this library are of a custom ContentType.

Any idea? Someone who encountered this kind of problem?

**UPDATE 13/09/2018 :**

Recently we went through a major update in the way these libraries work together : Now we've got some documents, *and* some pictures that share the *same* content type, inside *one* library. 
And we still experience the same problem : the number of hits on the images, wether we display them directly in the browser, or show the DisplayForm of the items, or even download the pictures... nothing seems to trigger the increment.

And I don't understand why since I can't find anything in Microsoft's documentation mentionning any specific behavior of the Usage Analytics service when it comes to pictures... pictures are just a specific type of document right ? And the documents located just beside those images work fine with the views count; we only have to display them in the browser (they're PDFs), juste like we can do with pictures...

Answer (score 0):

The property LifeViewsCount doent return the property. It is because the property is not searchable and i couldn't find the way for change this or create a variable with the crawl property for use in the page layout.

Comment: Thanks for replying, actually we don't need to deal with this property, ViewsRecent would be enough if only it could work with both of the types of document and not just one of them... 
We do get some results on the PDFs and other content types across the site collection, but it just doesn't work with pictures, that's our problem.